# Not displaying tag ID in a textbox

Tags: c#

I have build a project where Employee swipes their RFID card and its saved in to database.
I have a textbox name txtSwipe in which Employees TAG id is getting displayed and other processes like Progressbar and different type of messages all are attached with that txtSwipe. I have written code on mouse click event of txtSwipe.

Now when Employee Swipes his/her card I don't want that Tag ID to be displayed to the user also on this click event only data is getting properly saved into database if I post code in text changed event or any other data is not getting saved properly.

Code I am using is here :

```
try
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    label1.Text = "Working...";
    Application.DoEvents();
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Datatab(rfid)values(@rfid)", con);     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfid", txtSwipe.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    txtSwipe.ResetText();
    label1.Text = "Done";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label1.Text = "Error";
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
int i;
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = 200;
for (i = 0; i &lt;= 200; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value = i;
}
```

Comment: in the code where is `tag`?

Comment: rfid is the tag which is getting displayed in textbox which i dont want to get displayed.

Comment: don't see rfid is set to any textbox either.

Comment: Then instead of invoking the `DisplayText()` method, create a new method that contains the code to store the tag in the database, and call that?

Comment: txtSwipe.AppendText(DispString); 
this line while reading the card but when i remove it nothing is getting dispplayed nor getting saved into database.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfid", txtSwipe.Text);` you should stop using `AddWithValue`. Please read this [Stop with AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks Pat for he heads up.

Comment: @CodeCaster i tried that but rfid is not getting saved into database

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by setting Passchar property of textbox Thanks for the Help.